# Redirect to Index Method having no parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, indexing, redirecttoaction, actionmethod

Please help me, in my controller I am having 2 action methods with same name called **"Index"** but with different parameters ..

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {...}

 [HttpPost] 

 public ActionResult Index(PickingMobile mi, string hdnSelectOperation, string btnMPSearch, string btnSearchMP)
        {...}
```

Now from other action I want to redirect to Index action which has no parameters

```
public ActionResult ConfirmBatchPicking(PickingMobile DirectPicking)
        {
...
 return RedirectToAction("Index", "ManualPickingSearch");// from here I need to redirect to first Index Method which does not have any parameters
          }
```

But when I keep the break point and debugging the sequence, the first Index method is not getting hit. Please help me , how to redirect to first Index action.

Comment: As your one of the Index method is HttpPost type, So When you call   return RedirectToAction("Index", "ControllerName"). This will redirect you to HttpGet method

Comment: But is not hitting the first Index method while debufgging

Answer (score 1):

1. RedirectToAction returns RedirectToRouteResult to browser in
   response. This response makes browser to make a new get request to
   another action method(in your case Index action in
   ManualPickingSearchcontroller)
2. Your second Index action (one with parameter) is attached with httpPost attribute.It means only post request can be made to it.

And so, when you say return RedirectToAction("Index", "ManualPickingSearch"); it will redirect to first action method by default. Its the default behavior. Its how it should work. Please check if you are missing something.(Check the controller Name)

Comment: Sure, As I have View Bag in that it is not showing in View Page so only I am having doubt

Comment: Yes after redirect if you want to maintain value use tempbag.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

Comment: OK, if you use `RedirectToAction("Index", "ManualPickingSearch");` it will redirect to `ManualPickingSearch` controller's `Index` method. Thanks!

Comment: Ya I want to redirect to the Index method in ManualPIckingSearch only. But the problem is I have 2 index mehtods

Comment: You don't need to put controller name if you want to call a method in same controller. As long as you don't put `[HttpPost]` in your first `Index`method, there will be no issues.

Comment: Are there any `Index` methods (Not `[HttpPost]` one) with different parameters ?

Comment: Ya I have one with no parameters